# Extract date from string + PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Hello I am tring to get date "8 January 2014" from given string.

```
Wednesday, 8 January 2014 at 17:40
```

It will be good if you can use `preg_replace`?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I have not idea with preg_replace but m usig it now $res = date('M d, Y',strtotime(trim(substr( $res,10,15))))   ;

Comment: I doubt you need to use preg_replace, since it's in a well formated format it shouldn't be any problem to convert it to a date with `strtotime` and then use `date` to formate it `$date = date("d F Y", strtotime("Wednesday, 8 January 2014 at 17:40"));`

Comment: This String give me defualt value January 01,1970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP `strtotime` is bad at understanding the word "at" so this code should work and not return 1970:

```
$date = date("d F Y", strtotime(str_replace('at ','',"Wednesday, 8 January 2014 at 17:40")));
echo $date;
```

You can change the format just as you want; just change the letter `d F Y` and the list of letter that returns different values can be found [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

Just made solution with explode() function:

```
$str = "Wednesday, 8 January 2014 at 17:40";
$ex1 = explode(", ", $str);
$ex2 = explode(" at", $ex1[1]);
$value = $ex2[0];
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class makes your life simpler !

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F Y \a\t G:i','Wednesday, 8 January 2014 at 17:40');
echo $date->format('j F Y'); //"prints" 8 January 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regex pattern like this:

```
$str = 'Wednesday, 8 January 2014 at 17:40';
$date = preg_replace('/\w+,\s([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)\sat\s([0-9:]+)/i', '$1', $str);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code to get 8 January 2014 for you :)

```
 <?php
    $txt = 'Wednesday, 8 January 2014 at 17:40';
preg_match('#(?<=,\s)\d{1,2}\s\w+\s\d{1,4}(?=\sat)#', $txt, $result);
    ?>
```